# Using pdo execute and commit for mutiple http requests

Tags: php, pdo

This is a sample pdo execute and commit example from php.net

```
<?php
/* Begin a transaction, turning off autocommit */
$dbh->beginTransaction();

/* Insert multiple records on an all-or-nothing basis */
$sql = 'INSERT INTO fruit
    (name, colour, calories)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

foreach ($fruits as $fruit) {
    $sth->execute(array(
        $fruit->name,
        $fruit->colour,
        $fruit->calories,
    ));
}

/* Commit the changes */
$dbh->commit();

/* Database connection is now back in autocommit mode */
?>
```

From what I understand, this enables me to faster insert thousand of rows in a table. Now, if I have a php file that is called 
http://localhost/insertFruit.php?name=x&color=y&calories=z
which basically collects those values and insert them into database.

Now if I want to take advantage of that PDO loop and execute, I can't. If there is 100 of submission of those insertFruit.php, how can I collect all those values, combine into an array and then commit ? Using a separate class, calling object, using global values etc?

I am sure there is better way to do this.

Comment: Why do you think it enables you to faster insert thousands of rows in a table? I think you might be confused a little, it's not how it works.

Answer (score 1):

> how can i collect all those values, combine into an array and then commit?

Although you can, you shouldn't.

Neither transactions nor prepared statements are suitable for the separate requests.

Not to mention that your initial question is groundless. You don't need a faster insert. Your inserts are already fast.

There is no "better" way. Premature optimization is the root of all evil. By trying to devise a "better" way you'll ruin whole system.

All you can do is cluster some data into single request. If you have several fruits in one request, you can use prepared statements to process them in a loop.